# How to create csv file using raw text data

Tags: php, excel, csv, excel-formula, export-to-csv

i am much confused at this point regarding the csv file creation and insert data in the database.
suppose i have below text data - that is of 45000 record set, i am posting dew of them below.

```
Winged Wheels in France, by Michael Myers Shoemaker                      45790

A Battle Fought on Snow Shoes, by Mary Cochrane Rogers                   45789

The German Classics of the Nineteenth and Twentieth Centuries,           45788
 Volume 11, by Friedrich Spielhagen, Theodor Storm,
 Wilhelm Raabe, Marion D. Learned and Ewald Eiserhardt
 [Subtitle: Masterpieces of German Literature
  Translated Into English]

Zofloya ou le Maure, Tomes 1-4, by Charlotte Dacre                       45787
 [Subtitle: Histoire du XVe si?cle]
 [Language: French]

Their Majesties as I Knew Them, by Xavier Paoli                          45786
 [Subtitle: Personal Reminiscences of the
  Kings and Queens of Europe]
 [Translator: Alexander Teixeira de Mattos]

New York Times Current History: The European War, Vol. 8,                45785
 Pt. 2, No. 1, July 1918, by Various

Gallery of Comicalities, by Robert Cruikshank,                           45784
 George Cruikshank and Robert Seymour
 [Subtitle: Embracing Humorous Sketches]

Katri, by Emil Nervander                                                 45783
 [Subtitle: Kertomus 17 vuosi-sadasta]
 [Language: Finnish]

The Little Brown Jug at Kildare, by Meredith Nicholson                   45782
 [Illustrator: James Montgomery Flagg]

Beaumont & Fletcher's Works (6 through 10), by Francis Beaumont          45781
 and John Fletcher
 [Subtitle: The Queen of Corinth; Bonduca; The Knight of the
  Burning Pestle; Loves Pilgrimage; The Double Marriage]

Beaumont & Fletcher's Works (1 through 5), by Francis Beaumont           45780
 and John Fletcher
 [Subtitle: A Wife for a Month; The Lovers Progress;
  The Pilgrim; The Captain; The Prophetess]

The Washington Historical Quarterly, Volume V, 1914, by Various          45779
 [Editor: Edmond S. Meany]

Minstrelsy of the Scottish Border Volume III of 3, by Walter Scott       45778
 [Subtitle: Consisting of Historical and Romantic Ballads,
  Collected In the Southern Counties of Scotland; With
  a Few Of Modern Date, Founded Upon Local Tradition.
  In Three Volumes. Vol. III]
```

What i want is simply insert `Winged Wheels in France, by Michael Myers Shoemaker` in one column and `45790` in other column of CSV. then i will be able to add them to my database.
moreover, e.g,

```
The German Classics of the Nineteenth and Twentieth Centuries,           
 Volume 11, by Friedrich Spielhagen, Theodor Storm,
 Wilhelm Raabe, Marion D. Learned and Ewald Eiserhardt
 [Subtitle: Masterpieces of German Literature
  Translated Into English]
```

i want to insert above text in this way:

```
The German Classics of the Nineteenth and Twentieth Centuries,           
     Volume 11, by Friedrich Spielhagen, Theodor Storm,
     Wilhelm Raabe, Marion D. Learned and Ewald Eiserhardt
```

means no this portion:

```
[Subtitle: Masterpieces of German Literature
      Translated Into English]
```

the `", by"` should also omitted and so my new data would be like this. so actually i need three columns in the csv.

```
1 | Winged Wheels in France | Michael Myers Shoemaker                     |   45790
2 | The German Classics of the Nineteenth and Twentieth Centuries,       
 Volume 11 | Friedrich Spielhagen, Theodor Storm,
 Wilhelm Raabe, Marion D. Learned and Ewald Eiserhardt                    | 45789
```

Please help in getting it inserted in excel file and create csv from it.

thank you all.

Comment: anyone for help please?

Comment: do you want to insert all the data in one row?

Comment: No sir, row by row..but in this fashion : 1 | Winged Wheels in France | Michael Myers Shoemaker                     |   45790
2 | The German Classics of the Nineteenth and Twentieth Centuries,       
 Volume 11 | Friedrich Spielhagen, Theodor Storm,
 Wilhelm Raabe, Marion D. Learned and Ewald Eiserhardt                    | 45789

Comment: please anyone? please.

Comment: where do you have this entire data? in file?

Comment: yes Sir in text file.

Comment: okay you want to get the data from the txt file and insert into each row in db right?

Comment: 100% percent right but in a format i required. without[] them as well.

Answer (score 0):

do like this 
(not tested)

```
$f = file_get_contents('yourtextfile.txt');
$f = preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]/s','',$f);
$f = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $f);
file_put_contents('temp.txt',$f);

$file = file('temp.txt');
foreach($file as $key => $line){
    if($line!=null || $line!='')
 {
   mysqli_query($connection,"insert into table1(column1) values('$line')");
 }
}
```

***edit***

```
$f = file_get_contents('tt.txt');
$f = preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]/s','',$f);
$keywords = preg_split("/[ ]{15}/", $f);
print_r(array_filter($keywords));
```

i'm still not clear,whether you have those numbers in your file or you have just mentioned it there!!

Comment: you populate them in single row

Comment: please see: insert into table1(column1) values('Winged Wheels in France, by Michael Myers Shoemaker 45790A Battle Fought on Snow Shoes, by Mary Cochrane Rogers 45789The German Classics of the Nineteenth and Twentieth Centuries, 45788);

Comment: do you have those line numbers in your text file? or you are just showing it like that?